# Do I have to remap UVs when changing size of texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm creating low poly models for my game(I create them in blender), and I'm using color palette(small texture with different color on each pixel) on which I map UVs on the color that I want. The problem is that I want to add more models and more colors to the palette in the future. How would this work if I would add one more row of colors to the bottom of texture? Would UVs be stretched or just stay in the same place (if they would be stretched I would have to remap UVs every time I add new color)?

There is example of how I would like this to work (arrow points at new row):
[image: palette]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UV are not absolute distance from origin, say you have a texture of 256x256 with 4 pictures, UV map is not 0, 64 , 128, 192.

UV is normalized, you have a 4x4 first so all values are 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75. So if you add a row, that won't place properly anymore.

You need 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6 and 0.8.

So yes you need to remap.

If those are sprite, Unity has a Sprite Editor which makes it real easy.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Unfortunately these aren't sprites :(